# Wash sell issue. I’m a bit confused new to trading. Question is do I pay taxes on that disallowed as profit?

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale

Do I pay taxes on only the $6000 or on both the 1.2mill and the 6000? USA

[image]

Comment: Tax law varies all over the world. You'll need to [edit] your question with a country tag for us to have any idea how to answer.

Comment: I did thank you

Answer (score 2):

The disallowed wash sale losses are netted against your "raw" gain or loss (proceeds minus basis) to give your taxable gain or loss. This has already been done for you in the "Gain or Loss" column, so your taxable capital gain is the $6k.

Comment: thank you for the clarity. I’ve been going crazy for the last week thinking I could possibly owe hundreds of thousands in taxes over making $6000